# RxAndroid Observable skips doOnComplete()

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm calling multiple Retrofit api simultanious and wait for its completion which is done properly by `Observable.zip()`. Now I want to implement progress.

**Here is my Implementation..**

```
private void preFetchData() {
    ApiInterface apiService1 = ApiClient.getWooRxClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    ApiInterface apiService2 = ApiClient.getRxClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("on_sale", "true");
    Observable<List<Product>> call1 = apiService1.getProducts1(map1)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                progress += 18;
                Log.e("Progress1", progress + "");
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                mProgressBar.setProgressText(progress + "%");
            });

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("featured", "true");
    Observable<List<Product>> call2 = apiService1.getProducts1(map2)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delaySubscription(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                progress += 18;
                Log.e("Progress2", progress + "");
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                mProgressBar.setProgressText(progress + "%");
            });

    Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("page", "1");
    map3.put("sort", "rating");
    map3.put("per_page", "10");
    Observable<List<Product>> call3 = apiService2.getCustomProducts1(map3)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delaySubscription(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                progress += 18;
                Log.e("Progress3", progress + "");
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                mProgressBar.setProgressText(progress + "%");
            });

    Map<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
    map4.put("page", "1");
    map4.put("sort", "popularity");
    map4.put("per_page", "10");
    Observable<List<Product>> call4 = apiService2.getCustomProducts1(map4)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delaySubscription(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                progress += 18;
                Log.e("Progress4", progress + "");
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                mProgressBar.setProgressText(progress + "%");
            });

    Observable<ResponseBody> call5 = apiService2.getCurrencySymbol()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delaySubscription(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                progress += 10;
                Log.e("Progress5", progress + "");
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                mProgressBar.setProgressText(progress + "%");
            });

    Observable<List<Category>> call6 = apiService1.getAllCategories()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delaySubscription(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                progress += 18;
                Log.e("Progress6", progress + "");
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                mProgressBar.setProgressText(progress + "%");

            });

    Observable<CombinedHomePage> combined = Observable.zip(call1, call2, call3, call4, call5, call6, CombinedHomePage::new);
    disposable = combined.subscribe(this::successHomePage, this::throwableError);
}

private void successHomePage(CombinedHomePage o) {
    Log.e("Response", "SUCCESS " + o.featuredProductList.size());
    Log.e("Response", "SUCCESS " + o.saleProductList.size());
    Log.e("Response", "SUCCESS " + o.topRatedProductList.size());
    Log.e("Response", "SUCCESS " + o.topSellerProductList.size());
    Log.e("Response", "SUCCESS " + o.CURRENCY);
    Log.e("Response", "SUCCESS " + o.categoryList.size());
}

private void throwableError(Throwable t) {
    Log.e("Response", "Fail");
}
```

**Here is the Logcat**

> First Run

```
E/Progress5: 10.0
E/Progress2: 28.0
E/Progress1: 46.0
E/Progress6: 64.0
E/Progress3: 82.0
E/Response: Featured List Size 5
E/Response: Sale List Size 7
E/Response: Rated List Size 10
E/Response: Seller List Size 10
E/Response: Currency $
E/Response: Category List Size 9
```

> Second Run

```
E/Progress5: 10.0
E/Progress2: 28.0
E/Progress1: 46.0
E/Progress6: 64.0
E/Progress4: 82.0
E/Response: Featured List Size 5
E/Response: Sale List Size 7
E/Response: Rated List Size 10
E/Response: Seller List Size 10
E/Response: Currency $
E/Response: Category List Size 9
```

In first run Progess 4 skips and in second run Progess 3 skips(All Api completed Properly).

Any Idea why this is happening?

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is described in the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

> The operator subscribes to its sources in order they are specified and completes eagerly if one of the sources is shorter than the rest while disposing the other sources. Therefore, it is possible those other sources will never be able to run to completion (and thus not calling doOnComplete()). This can also happen if the sources are exactly the same length; if source A completes and B has been consumed and is about to complete, the operator detects A won't be sending further values and it will dispose B immediately. For example:
>
> `zip(Arrays.asList(range(1, 5).doOnComplete(action1),
>      range(6, 5).doOnComplete(action2)), (a) -> a)`
>
> action1 will be called but action2 won't. 
>   To work around this termination property, use doOnDispose(Action) as well or use using() to do cleanup in case of completion or a dispose() call.

Comment: ok bro thanks but can you provide pseudo code for workaround i'm new to rxjava. `doOnDispose()` may call in case of fail?

Comment: might make sense in this case to use `doOnNext()`

Comment: Just replace `doOnComplete` with `doFinally` or, as John O'reilly suggested, `doOnNext` if you know there will be only 1 item per source.

Comment: Thanks @JohnO'Reilly and @akarnokd `doOnNext` is working fine.